# How to properly wrap div element with a element

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

I can't seem to properly wrap a `div` element with an `a` tag.

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="mx-2 facebook"></div></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="mx-2 twitter"></div></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="mx-2 instagram"></div></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="mx-2 snapchat"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is scss but anyone who knows css should be able to understand it somewhat

```
@mixin social-icon($hover-color, $icon) {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;

  &:hover {background-color: $hover-color;}

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    content: $icon;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
}

ul {
    list-style: none;

    li {
      display: inline;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.25rem;

      div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
      }

    }
  }

.facebook {@include social-icon(#3B5998, "\f39e");}
.twitter {@include social-icon(#1dcaff, "\f099");}
.instagram {@include social-icon(#e1306c, "\f16d");}
.snapchat {@include social-icon(#fffc00, "\f2ac");}
```

[Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/iCodeCoolStuff/pen/JqWWrQ)

The bounds of the `a` tag go along fine with the `li` tag, but when the `div` element gets involved, the `a` tag just ignores the bounds of the `div` element and just stays where it's at.

[image]
[image]

Comment: make the `a` inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why *div*? Why not:

```
<li><a href="#" class="mx-2 facebook"></a></li>
```

```
ul {
   li {
     a {
       display:inline-block;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: isn't <a> inline-block by default?

Comment: @Frish no, it's inline by default

Answer (score 0):

Add the display attribute for the link to `display: inline-block`. Doing this alone leaves a little bit of overhang, changing the div using `display: block` the div and the link at the same size. I'd also recommend setting the li to `display: inline-flex`.

I've added it to the SCSS below

```
@mixin social-icon($hover-color, $icon) {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;

  &:hover {background-color: $hover-color;}

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    content: $icon;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
}

ul {
    list-style: none;

    li {
      display: inline-flex;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.25rem;

      a { 
        display: inline-block;
      }

      div {
        display: block;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
      }

    }
  }

.facebook {@include social-icon(#3B5998, "\f39e");}
.twitter {@include social-icon(#1dcaff, "\f099");}
.instagram {@include social-icon(#e1306c, "\f16d");}
.snapchat {@include social-icon(#fffc00, "\f2ac");}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this doesn't seem to matter much since the clickable link area still seems to extend to the size of the div very well. But if you care to fix it just add

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Although, you may not want to select all a tags globally like I did. This solution will still make the a tag little larger than the div. For the perfectionist you can try.

```
@mixin social-icon($hover-color, $icon) {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;

  &:hover {background-color: $hover-color;}

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    content: $icon;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
}

ul {
    list-style: none;

    li {
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      width: 2rem;
      height: 2rem;

      div {
        // display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        // width: 2rem;
        // height: 2rem;
      }

    }
  }

.facebook {@include social-icon(#3B5998, "\f39e");}
.twitter {@include social-icon(#1dcaff, "\f099");}
.instagram {@include social-icon(#e1306c, "\f16d");}
.snapchat {@include social-icon(#fffc00, "\f2ac");}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```